# Moving SQL Server 2008 R2 backup/restore to detach/reattach

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, automated-tests, database-backups, database-restore

I'm working on updating a framework to test database driven code.  Before every write test to the database it's doing a [RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) of a database backup, which is taking 15-20 seconds, so I'm trying to speed it up by keeping a "backup" of detached mdf, ldf, and ndf files so that I can just [CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) before every test.  The problem is that when using RESTORE, you can "move" (or, more specifically, choose where to restore the backup into) the mdf, ldf, and ndf files with something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [testDB]
  FROM DISK = N'\\Path\To\Backup' WITH FILE = 1, RECOVERY,
  MOVE N'testDB' TO N'\\Path\To\MDF', 
  MOVE N'testDB_log' TO N'\\Path\To\LDF', 
  MOVE N'ftrow_testDB' TO N'\\Path\To\NDF', 
  NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 1
```

However, with CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH, I can't seem to find any way to "move" the mdf, ldf, and ndf files.  When you attach, it just uses the files you specify as the database files:

```
CREATE DATABASE [testDB] ON
  (FILENAME = N'\\Path\To\MDF'),
  (FILENAME = N'\\Path\To\LDF'),
  (FILENAME = N'\\Path\To\NDF')
FOR ATTACH
```

This means to keep a "backup" of those three files I'll need to copy them from a backup directory every time, which is time consuming and more than cancels out any speed gains.

Anyone have any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out any way to get this to work, so I just shrunk the databases as much as I could and put them in simple recovery mode - that sped it up a decent amount.